# Add delay between layers in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

How to add randomized processing **delay** before passing the packets to upper / lower layers?

Directly in the  ini file. Is there any easy way without editing  the c++ code?

I tried processingDelayLayer at the sender and receiver. But no impact.

```
################

*.client.processingDelayLayer.egress.delay = 12s
*.client.processingDelayLayer.ingress.delay = 0s

 
*.server.processingDelayLayer.ingress.delay = 10s
*.server.processingDelayLayer.egress.delay = 0s
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a **very** bad idea. A randomized delay would change the ordering of the packets passed between the layers. That is definitely something that does not happen in real life systems. A fixed, non-random delay may or may not be ok.

INET supports modeling processing delay in Switches where it models the processing time requires to do the work to decide where to forward the packet. But still, the delay must be constant.

Comment: Thanks, Does this code means consider the network  traffic? or am I understand wrong? 




# Each application has its own message length and sending interval,
# which determine the amount of data sent and the rate at which it is sent, respectively.
# background - 24Mbps
*.client.app[0].messageLength = 900B
*.client.app[0].sendInterval = normal(300us,10us)

# best effort - 28.8Mbps
*.client.app[1].messageLength = 900B
*.client.app[1].sendInterval = normal(250us,10us)